# Javascript returns php array incorrectly for jssor slider

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, jssor

I have a working installation of the jssor slider. The way it changes the images is determined by transition strings in the code. There are hundreds of transitions available and I am trying to write code to load those in as picked by the user. I have a php function that finds the picked transition and that is then used in the javascript.

The problem is that it doesn't work. As far as I can tell, it looks like the returned array is not being decoded correctly.

The file I am using to store the transitions has content like this:

```
    fade = {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}
    bounce_down = {$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}
```

My php code is:

```
    function GetTransitions() {
      $picked = array(0 => 'bounce_down'); //just to show what was picked

      $xsisitons = array();
      $xit = parse_ini_file('transitions.ini');

      foreach ($xit as $key => $data) { 
        if (in_array($key, $picked)) {
            $xsisitons[] = $data; 
        }
      } 
      return json_encode($xsisitons);
    }

    $jsondata = GetTransitions();
```

The relevant part of the javascript is

```
    <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

     var xsitions = <?php echo $jsondata; ?>

     console.log(xsitions);

     var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            xsitions
            ];
```

If I paste the transition string directly into the above _SlideshowTransitions, the transition works. But if it is loaded as shown, the transition fails.

The output of the console.log is

```
    ["{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}"]
```

That's different from the original string since it is enclosed in [" "]. Assuming that is the problem, how do I return the correct string? Or can someone see some other problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `json_decode` to decode the string `$data` you read from ini file.

```
function GetTransitions() {
  $picked = array(0 => 'bounce_down'); //just to show what was picked

  $xsisitons = array();
  $xit = parse_ini_file('transitions.ini');

  foreach ($xit as $key => $data) { 
    if (in_array($key, $picked)) {
        $xsisitons[] = json_decode($data); 
    }
  } 
  return json_encode($xsisitons);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I changed the code so that the php function is not used to see where the problem is. If I replace <?php echo $jsondata; ?> with {$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}; it works. If I display the php value, it is displayed like that. But if I display the xsition variable after it is directly set, it is shown as [object Object]. So, I guess I need to convert the php return to an object. A search for this shows I need to use JSON.parse. I tried JSON.parse(xsitions) but it gives an unexpected token error. How do I convert the php item to an object?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to join the array items.

```
function GetTransitions() {
  $picked = array(0 => 'bounce_down'); //just to show what was picked

  $xsisitons = array();
  $xit = parse_ini_file('transitions.ini');

  foreach ($xit as $key => $data) { 
    if (in_array($key, $picked)) {
        $xsisitons[] = $data; 
    }
  } 
  return '[' . join(',', $xsisitons) . ']';
}
```

Comment: I had to replace the [] with () but that worked. Thank you. The purpose of this is to allow more than one transition at a time. In the regular code, a comma is needed after each transition string. I tried adding a comma at various places, like after the $data and before the ']' but that causes errors. I found code to loop through a javascript object thinking to change it there but I couldn't  that to work either. Would you please explain how to add a comma after each transitions string?

Comment: You can add comma to every transition except the last one.

Comment: I didn't realize the code you posted, with the join, was adding commas already. I echoed the output using php and see the commas are there. But when the result is displayed in javascript - console.log(xsitions) - it just shows the last item added to the array. Do I have to convert the returned xsitions somehow to get all of the items in the array?

Comment: If comma is in the returned transitions, it should work with no problem.

Comment: So, you can debug to see how many transitions are there in the `$xsisitons` array.

Comment: If I check the return from the function in php, I get an array of all of the transitions with a comma after each one except the last one. But when checked from within javascript, the comma is not there. Here's what I see as output from php:
 ["{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}",
 "{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}"] 
And output from console.dir 
0: "{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}"​
1: "{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}"

Comment: It should be `[{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}, {$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}] `. Please use `view source` command of browser to see the output.

Comment: The source has that but with quotes: ["{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}","{$Duration:1000,y:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InBounce,$Opacity:2}"];  I tried a str_replace in the php code to remove the quotes but they are still there so I guess json_encode is adding them. I don't know how to remove them from the object in javascript, assuming that is what's needed? Any thoughts on how to remove those or are they not the issue?